# C# Fraction wont go through with a Reduce() method

Tags: c#

I need to multiply two fractions then reduce the resulting fraction, but I don't know how make my resulting fraction go through my Reduce(); method.

```
public class Fraction
{
    public static Fraction operator * (Fraction fract1, Fraction fract2)
    {
        int numerato = fract1.numerator * fract2.numerator;
        int denominato = fract1.denominator * fract2.denominator;
        return new Fraction(numerato, denominato).Reduce();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need parentheses, as in `return new Fraction(numerato, denominato).Reduce();`

Comment: I added the paratheses, but another error shows up. "Cannot convert type 'void' to 'Fraction'

Comment: Either your `Reduce()` method needs to return `this`, or you need to reduce the fraction in one step and then return the reduced fraction in the next step.

Comment: I'm not sure how to approach the problem.  My reduce method is private, 'private void Reduce()'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to write operator * and Reduce():

```
    public static Fraction operator * (Fraction fract1, Fraction fract2)
    {
        int numerato = fract1.numerator * fract2.numerator;
        int denominato = fract1.denominator * fract2.denominator;
        return new Fraction (numerato, denominato).Reduce ();
    }

    private Fraction Reduce()
    {
        int gcd = Gcd (numerator, denominator);
        numerator = numerator / gcd;
        denominator = denominator / gcd;
        return this;
    }
```

And here is another way

```
    public static Fraction operator * (Fraction fract1, Fraction fract2)
    {
        int numerato = fract1.numerator * fract2.numerator;
        int denominato = fract1.denominator * fract2.denominator;
        Fraction f = new Fraction (numerato, denominato);
        f.Reduce ();
        return f;
    }

    private void Reduce()
    {
        int gcd = Gcd (numerator, denominator);
        numerator = numerator / gcd;
        denominator = denominator / gcd;
    }
```

Now compare these and notice the differences.

Comment: I would be surprised if `private Fraction Reduce` returned `this` instead of a new `Fraction`.

Comment: @Gabe: Yes, but I expect it would be a void method used internally so that Fractions are always reduced after any operation.